# Cartoon style name

Tags: illustration, style-identification

fellow designers)
I need to do mood board for the project with specific cartoon art style like on this img: [image: this img] but I can't figure out, what to type in the search. Is it some old cartoons from specific time period? It has some elements of it. Or maybe graffiti? It has some sloppiness too. I met this art style before, it was popular in 90s, I think. I need more of this and will be greatful for any help here(

Comment: It's a modern take on a 1920s/30s vibe. idk if it has a specific name, but google '1920 cartoon' or 'looney tunes' for original examples.

Comment: oh, thanks. I already googled 30s cartoons and pretty familiar with looney tunes and tax avery cartoons, but didn't try to add 'modern'. Maybe I'll be lucky with some artists names and not only with Cuphead xD

Comment: @Testujin That's an answer that I'd upvote. Please do not answer questions in the comments, even if the answer is short.

Comment: Perhaps the typo in Tex Avery's name confused your search engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not quite clear what you’re looking for as cartoon illustrations have had similar styles to what you posted throughout the decades; however, one notable artist for vintage Santa Cruz skateboards was Jim Phillips.

Jim’s artwork is very popular. One of the most iconic pieces is a hand with a mouth in its palm. https://goo.gl/images/9KCHkZ

For other phrases, consider:

- retro skate art
- rip grip art

Answer (score 10):

This style is derivative, albeit much tamer, of Ed "Big Daddy" Roth illustrations. His work is a quintessential example of 1950s and 60s hot rod culture, in particular, **Southern California Kustom Kulture**:

[image]

> Sources:
>    • [Ed Roth - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_Roth)
>    • [Kustom Kulture - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kustom_Kulture)
>    • [The Official Site of Rat Fink and Ed    Roth](http://www.ratfink.com/)

Comment: Wow, I think this is it! x) I was close when I get to the Californian skate culture. Thank you! I think, now I can do my work

Comment: @eide if you think this is the correct answer then you should mark it as accepted.
On the other hand, I think Kustom graphics are too gritty compared to the illustration in question.

Comment: Agreed @Luciano..."This style is derivative, albeit much tamer..."

Answer (score 9):

I once met with the **Steamboat Willie style**, which refers to the great animation by Walt Disney. It looks like it was the best reference to things like **Cuphead**.

I think the best way to find something of that style, is to write **Vintage cartoon**, or **Vintage cartoon art**. Here is the example found in Google:

[image]

Comment: although your example is dated 2014... too recent to be vintage!

Comment: @Luciano Maybe it's like _Nineteen Eighty-Four_!

Comment: @Luciano - Back to the future:D

Answer (score 1):

It's called Rubber hose animation y'all :~)

Comment: Can you explain why you think this is it? I believe rubber hose is the style of animation of the limbs, but perhaps vintage 20's describes it better.

Answer (score 0):

Fleischer is what the style was called. Short bodies with rubber hoses for limbs

Comment: the style in question is not Fleischer, check the other answers