# Is there a name for this cartoon style?

Tags: style-identification

I wonder if this kind of cartoon style has a specific name. They were acquired from a specific artist, but I can't find similar assets that integrate well with them, and I even tried adjusting in Photoshop other images to fit this style, with no success.

I noticed they use bright colors (but few of them to highlight the shadows), a black outline and disproportionate large heads.

[image: Cartoon images from Craftpix.net]

Comment: Not all styles of artwork have some specific name.

Comment: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/112882/cartoon-style-name | https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/137628/what-is-the-name-of-this-style-of-design-illustration-where-cartoony-items-are-s

Comment: "grumpy Bitmoji"?

Comment: disproportionally large heads are the hallmark of the “chibi” cartoon style.